# $facebook->getUser() returns 0 after moving to new hosting

Tags: php, facebook, bluehost

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1. This code works fine for me on my previous hosting. I've just moved it to BlueHost and the value of $user is always 0 even when user already logged in:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APIKEY,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Any idea why this can happen?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Facebook SDK, but if I had to guess, I'd say check to see how it's communicating with Facebook (curl, maybe?) and check that that isn't blocked by the host. If I had to bet, I'd say it's the network connection being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The `getUser()` function uses the `$_REQUEST['signed_request'])` global.

And since you said you recently switched hosting accounts, it is possible that the server is configured either to turn off `$_REQUEST` or somehow override it.

You can check these php.ini variables, because they affect `$_REQUEST`:

- variables_order
- request_order

The see these variables do `phpinfo();` in your template, which is going to print out all the necessary information.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Otherwise, you might need to contact your hosting provider and ask about the `$_REQUEST` global, to see if you can use it.

Comment: What is $_REQUEST['signed_request'] supposed to be? I printed it out but there is nothing there.

Comment: So that is why the getUser() function returns 0. $_REQUEST might be disabled in the server configuration. I've updated my answer with the steps you might take.

Comment: What should these two variables be? My variables_order is EGPCS. There is no request_order.

Comment: It's just a very long key, an access token. It shouldn't be empty, that's for sure. So I would suggest contacting your hosting provider.